# File lock (flock) compatibility between C and Python

Tags: python, c, linux, locking

Does the python implementation of flock work transparently along with standard C libraries? If I have two programs, one in Python and the other in C, trying acquire a lock on a single file will it work?

**Quick links:**

1. Python flock: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html
2. Linux flock: http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's `fcntl` library is built directly on top of the standard C libraries; so on Linux `fcntl.flock()` uses the `flock` C function *directly*.

See the [source code for the `fcntl` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/fcntlmodule.c#l250):

```c
#ifdef HAVE_FLOCK
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    ret = flock(fd, code);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

This is clearly stated in the [`fcntl.flock()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) as well:

> **`fcntl.flock(fd, op)`**
>   Perform the lock operation op on file descriptor *fd* (file objects providing a `fileno()` method are accepted as well). See the Unix manual *flock(2)* for details. (On some systems, this function is emulated using `fcntl()`.)

So yes, it'll work.